# What are the limits/powers of android device policy?

Tags: security, privacy

I work in a university and when we want to login in our university email id, we go to gmail

So we can also use our official email for creating account on android,but when i try to create account using my university email id, i am prompted to install android device policy, i am not certain regarding its limits? How much power will this policy give to our university IT admin, will it give access to private data(facebook,whatsapp etc) phone contacts lists and banking data etc on our android device?

Comment: That totally depends on how it is configured by your university. You need to ask them not here

Comment: I am not aware of a way how a managed device should allow access to app-private data. In general a device policy disables certain insecure settings on your device (e.g. requires a lockscreen pin/password). A sample list of device management options available for Android devices can e.g. be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/compliance-policy-create-android As the interface on Android side is the same for all device management systems the policy options are more or less the same for all those MDM solutions.

Comment: From: https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#personally-owned_devices `A work profile provides a self-contained space for work apps and data, separate from personal apps and data. Most app, data, and other management policies apply to the work profile only, while the employee's personal apps and data remain private.`